# Cauchy-Riemann question

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I have managed to do parts a, b and c(i). However, I am stuck on the remainder of the question. I was wondering if I could get any hints?

Comment: Hint d)Sum of two analytic function is again analytic!

Comment: c)Follow the steps given in problem and conclude that $u_x=u_y=v_x=v_y=0$.Let me know if you have some problem!

Answer (score 1):

Add indeed the two identities you have reached

$$\left(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}\right)^2=0$$

And the second order derivatives vanish because of $\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x^2}}+\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{y^2}}=0$ and $\frac{\partial^2{v}}{\partial{x^2}}+\frac{\partial^2{v}}{\partial{y^2}}=0$

So we have a sum of four squares that is nil and therefore each of the terms is zero and therefore $u$ and $v$ are constants and $f$ is constant.

The last question follows the same principle taking into account that $\bar{f}(z)=u-iv$